# Swig, python and output strings

Tags: python, c, swig

I am using Swig to wrap a C interface that looks like this:

```
int dosomething(char **str);
```

where str is an output string.  For example, from C its called like this:

```
char *str= NULL;
int val= dosomething(&str);
   ...
free(str);
```

In Python, I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
val,str = dosomething()
```

However, python keeps reporting

```
TypeError: dosomething() takes exactly 1 arguments (0 given)
```

I've tried using OUTPUT in a typemap, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: may I suggest you try ctypes? Its much faster to port C functions this way

Comment: Unfortunately, ctypes is python-only. I'm using swig because I need to wrap for many different languages (Java, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this typemap (I'm using SWIG 2.0.0):

```
%include <cstring.i>
%cstring_output_allocate(char **str, free(*$1));
```

Documentation: [cstring.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn12)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use it normally, passing a parameter, and wrap it inside python to return a tuple?